# What is meant by bounding box in android map view

Tags: android, bounding-box

I am sorry if it seems a silly question to you, but I have been dealing with some problems in my android project and my client constantly refers to the term bounding box. Can someone please tell me what exactly is Bounding-box ,with ref to map view in android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term *bounding box* typically refers to the rectangular space taken up by an item on screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a bounding box to limit the search criteria of the Geocoder's getFromLocationName method by giving it the lower left and upper right latitude/longitudes as arguments.

Also if you are using osmdroid to implement an OpenStreetMap mapview rather than a Google mapview, then there is a class in that library named  org.osmdroid.util.BoundingBoxE6